# Asset font is not loaded in android webView

Tags: android, css, fonts, webview

I'm developing an android activity which is loading an HTML file into a webview. 
 However this acitivty is not loading fonts in some phones e.g. HTC Desire or Sony Xperia Z with 4.4 or 4.1 androids. 
 I want to know if i have missed something or it is only depends on phone which i'm testing my app.

```
private void loadToWebView(String s) {
    try {
        pageWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", s,
                "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        configureWebView(pageWebView);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

here is html header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<style type="text/css">
@font-face { font-family: 'Persian'; src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/b_yekan.ttf'); }
@font-face { font-family: 'Persian2'; src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/b_homa.ttf'); }
@font-face { font-family: 'PersianTitle'; src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/b_titr.ttf');}
body {font-family: 'Persian';}
h1 {font-family: 'PersianTitle';}
h2 {font-family: 'Persian2';}
</style>
```

fonts are located in assets/fonts/ like this 
[image]

Comment: is it working for other devices?

Comment: i have no other devices to test right now! i will test on emulator and let you know

Comment: @MehulJoisar it is not also working on emulator

Comment: @VSB, did you try the solution I posted?

Comment: @shoerat yes, unfortunately it did not helped. I posted a comment about that but i don't know where is it now?

Comment: Strange, I never saw that comment. Can you explain how exactly it did not work? Also, can you tell how your HTML and CSS files are structured?

Comment: @shoerat I have updated the question with HTML and css structure. CSS is inside `<style>` tags pf HTML.

Comment: @shoerat as you noticed problem is about persian script. google fonts worked well!

Comment: That's the limitation of the older platforms, there is nothing to be done about it at this moment

Comment: @shoerat stragne situation is both phones running android 4.3 & 4.1! both support persian well, however do not display persian fonts inside webView :(

Comment: Are those fonts publicly available?

Comment: they are available at [http://www.bornaray.com/products/font.html] e.g. you can find 'B Homa' or 'B Lotus'. On some phones they are loaded or some phones they are loaded in normal controls of android such as textview but not inside webview.

Comment: @VSB, I stand correct. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: @shoerat i did check that however the problem still exists. in my phones, only default font displayed for persian.

Answer (score 23):

- **First of all**, fonts path should be relative to your HTML/CSS file.

So, instead of this:

```
@font-face { font-family: 'Persian'; src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/b_yekan.ttf'); }
```

Use something like this:

```
@font-face { font-family: 'Persian'; src: url('fonts/b_yekan.ttf'); }
```

- **Second**, you must make sure that the target you are testing against actually supports Arabic script.

With that, below I am providing a working example.

---

*assets/about_us.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face { font-family: 'B Homa'; src: url('fonts/BHOMA.TTF');}
    @font-face { font-family: 'B Lotus'; src: url('fonts/BLOTUS.TTF');}
    @font-face { font-family: 'B Lotus Bold'; src: url('fonts/BLOTUSBD.TTF');}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <p style="font-family:'B Homa';font-size:20px;">B Homa: مخصص</p>
    <p style="font-family:'B Lotus';font-size:20px;">B Lotus: مخصص</p>
    <p style="font-family:'B Lotus Bold';font-size:20px;">B Lotus Bold: مخصص</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**BHOMA.TTF**, **BLOTUS.TTF** and **BLOTUSBD.TTF** are downloaded from [bornaray.com](http://www.bornaray.com/products/font.html) and stored in `assets/fonts/` folder.

*loadToWebView()*, it is part of a `Fragment`, hence `getActivity().getAssets()`:

```
private void loadToWebView() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getActivity().getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream input = assetManager.open("about_us.html");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];
        input.read(buffer);
        input.close();
        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",
                new String(buffer), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

*And the result*:

[image: Screenshot]

Hope this helps.

Comment: how did you get this results? did you use emulator or a real device?

Comment: @KhalidElSayed real device, Nexus ⒌

Comment: @ozbek How can I make sure that the target I am testing against actually supports Arabic script? tnx.

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki: Android supports Arabic natively since [version 4.2](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#RTL). You may check if the target SDK is >= 17 and assume that Arabic is supported.

Comment: @ozbek So, before this version I cannot do anything, right?  tnx for answer ;)

Comment: @ozbek - please add closing curly brackets '}' on the initial 2 code lines. StackOverflow won't allow me to post an edit with fewer than 6 characters!

Comment: Thank you alot @ozbek. That line fixed my problem mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",
                new String(buffer), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);