# android address font to HTML which exists on Assets

Tags: android, html, file, fonts, assets

I have code below :

```
HTMLcode = "<html>\n"
            + "<head>\n"
            + "<style>\n"
            + "@font-face {\n"
            + "font-family: 'MyFont';\n"
            + "src: url('"
            + Fontadress
            + "');\n"
            + "}\n"
            + "body{\n"
            + "font-family: 'MyFont';\n"
            + "text-align:center;\n"
            + "vertical-align:center;\n"
            + "font-size:20;\n"
            + "}\n"
            + "</style>\n"
            + "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n"
            + "<title>title of page </title>\n"
            + "</head>\n"
            + "<body>\n"
            + "<marquee behavior=\"scroll\" dir=\"rtl\" direction=\"right\" scrollamount=\"3\">\n"
            + Marquetext + "</marquee>\n" + "</body></html>\n";
```

which will simply create my desired HTML code.but problem is that when I send `file:///android_assets/fonts/Zar.ttf` inside  `Fontadress` variable it doesn't affect on HTML page.Why this is so?and how can I fix this?

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077094/asset-font-is-not-loaded-in-android-webview

Comment: I did but my problem is different I want to use a font which is in assets inside a HTML file which is not in assets..(in link that you sent both were on assets)